# PHP adding up MD5 hashes?

Tags: php, md5

I'm using + sign to **add up 2 MD5 hashes** like so:

```
md5('string1') + md5('string2')
```

now if I did this **with strings**, like so:

```
'string1' + 'string2'
```

...PHPp would give me 0 as a return value. However, with MD5 hashes, it always returns a numeric value, for which I cannot determine any origin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will depend on the hash values generated by your strings. When adding "string" values, PHP's behaviour (and it is [well documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)) is to take any leading numeric characters and treat them as an integer... if there are no leading numerics, then it will be treated as 0.

So

```
"1st String" + "2nd String" => 1 + 2 => 3
```

With your data

```
md5('string1') = '34b577be20fbc15477aadb9a08101ff9'
md5('string2') = '91c0c59c8f6fc9aa2dc99a89f2fd0ab5'
```

giving

```
34 + 91 => 125
```

Now why are you trying to add hash values?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, md5 function returns string value but md5 algorithm generates hexadecomal values.

Also remember PHP support some automated casting.

That is why php will give some values but you can't detect that value as even a single character change in string completely changes generated MD5 hash.

Still question is very interesting. Can you please let us know what are you trying to achieve by adding md5 hash?

Comment: +1 for the info, didn't know md5 creates hexa... about why we do it - it was basically sort of a mistake where we used + instead of . and then discovered we're getting wierd results :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add md5 hashes with `+` just as you cannot add any other kind of strings with `+`. The difference is expected and due to PHP's [rules for string to number conversion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion). Contrast this:

```
'1string' + '2string'
```

with

```
'string1' + 'string2'
```

If numerically adding md5s gives you a result different from zero, it is because *by chance* the specific hashes you are adding start with one or more decimal digits.

There can be no legitimate reason to add two strings that do not represent decimal numbers, so don't do it.

Answer (score -1):

In PHP, `+` is numerical addition and `.` is string concatenation.

Also, `md5(string)` returns a **string**...

So:

```
$hashes = md5('string1') . md5('string2');
```

You probably want to numerically add hashes. Then you would need to convert the MD5 result to a number using [hexdec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php).

Comment: Not my downvote, but `hexdec` is obviously not going to work here because MD5s are 128 bits, which means that it would convert to a float, which means that you would lose precision, which means that the result would not be accurate.

Comment: If I interpret the OP's question correctly, he's not asking how to concatenate two MD5 hashes. He's asking why the `+` operator returns a non-zero integer when it usually returns zero when used with strings.